# How to correctly partition buffered socket data when no explicit delimiter is used?

Tags: python, json, sockets, buffer, partitioning

I am receiving data from a socket. The data consists of json logs with unspecified lengths and no explicit delimiters between them. To get the whole json objects out of the buffer, I use the Python's partition() method with "'}" given as the seperator parameter because when there is  "'}", I know it's the end of a json object. I cannot just use "}" since some of the logs are nested json objects. And this approach mostly works because all the fields except one have string values. So, almost always there is a quotation mark just before the closing curly bracket. But when the last field of the json object is an integer, I cannot partition the logs correctly. How can I achieve this?

```
class Buffer:

    def __init__(self,sock):
        self.sock = sock
        self.buffer = b''

    def get_line(self):
        while b"'}" not in self.buffer:
            log_b = self.sock.recv(8192)
            if not log_b:
                return None
            self.buffer += log_b

        log_p, sep, self.buffer = self.buffer.partition(b"'}")
        log_p = log_p + sep
        return log_p
```

Example log with string ending:

```
b"{'username': 'user1', 'computer': 'computer1', 'activity': 'file', 'is_directory': False, 'event_type': 'modified', 'src': 'C:\\\\Windows\\\\Prefetch\\\\something.exe', 'event_time': '2022-08-19T10:13:41.033268'}"
```

Example log with integer ending:

```
b"{'username': 'user1', 'computer': 'computer1', 'activity': 'application', 'session_id': '63813953xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'name': 'example.exe', 'state': 'closed','event_time': '2022-08-19T13:19:32.934791', 'open_seconds': 6}"
```

Example return value when there's a log with integer ending (Some string operations are done on the log but they're irrelevant to this problem):

```
{"username": "user1", "computer": "computer1", "activity": "application", "session_id": "29ea56ba-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "name": "example.exe", "state": "closed", "event_time": "2022-08-19T13:13:41.330154", "open_seconds": 6}{"username": "user2", "computer": "computer2", "activity": "file", "is_directory": false, "event_type": "modified", "src": "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\Scans\\example.db-wal", "event_time": "2022-08-19T10:15:11.426459"}
```

Example log with another set of curly braces inside:

```
 {"activity": "file", "is_directory": false, "event_type": "modified", "src": "C:\\System Volume Information\\xxx\\xxx\\{cd42efe1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
4219 {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}", "event_time": "2022-08-12T10:21:39.913103"}
```

Comment: What would be an example of a log with nested JSON? If that's something you're going to have to deal with, you might have to keep track of opening `{` and closing `}` braces.

Comment: @MattDMo I couldn't find any saved example for nested json objects but I added an example that has another set of curly braces inside it. That causes the same problem as a nested json object.

Comment: @m.yagmur Could you use [`json.raw_decode`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode)? (to validate you have the right `}`)

Comment: @AndrejKesely Could you elaborate please? How would I use json.raw_decode for validation in this case?

Comment: maybe you change your code and first send size of data as single `byte` or `word` (2 bytes) and  later data - this way receiver will know how much data it has to receive

Comment: or maybe you should count chars `{` and `}` - and when you get the same number of `{` and `}` then you may have end of data. (ie. when you find new `{` then `counter += 1`, when you find new `}` then `counter -= 1` - and alter check if you have `counter == 0`

Answer (score 0):

I would seperate the strings on `}{` and then re-add the curly brackets to the JSON. `}{` can't exist in normal JSON as there should always be at least a comma between two nested JSON's, so this always indicates that two JSON's were joined there. The only place where this could occur, is in the strings inside the JSON, so if any of these strings contains `}{`, then you can't use this method.

Here's the code, `splitted` will contain a list with the splitted strings:

```py
string = "{'username': 'user1', 'computer': 'computer1', 'activity': 'file', 'is_directory': False, 'event_type': 'modified', 'src': 'C:\\\\Windows\\\\Prefetch\\\\something.exe', 'event_time': '2022-08-19T10:13:41.033268'}{'username': 'user1', 'computer': 'computer1', 'activity': 'application', 'session_id': '63813953xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'name': 'example.exe', 'state': 'closed','event_time': '2022-08-19T13:19:32.934791', 'open_seconds': 6}"
splitted = string.split("}{")

for i in range(len(splitted)):
    if not splitted[i].endswith("}"):
        splitted[i] += "}"
    if not splitted[i].startswith("{"):
        splitted[i] = "{" + splitted[i]
```